# Android: Persisting Data using Perst Lite, How to persist deleted data?

Tags: java, android, listview, persistence, persist

I have an application that has a ListView of movies declared in strings.xml as a string-array. There are 3 elements in each ListView row corresponding to the 3 string-array, namely, Title, Gross and Date. The user can add movies by clicking on the add button in the menu, and he/she is sent to a 2nd screen with 3 EditTexts where he/she can add the details of his/her new movie. Similarly, the user can also delete and edit entries.

I am using PerstLite as a means of persisting data changes in my code, however, I can only do the "add" function. Here is my code:

My OnCreate:

```
   String databasePath = getAbsolutePath("movies.dbs");

    // open the database
    db.open(databasePath, 40 * 1024);

    // check if a root object is present in this file
    Index<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> root = (Index<Lab8_082588FetchDetails>) db
            .getRoot();
    if (root == null) {
        // Root is not yet defined: storage is not initialized
        root = (Index) db.createIndex(String.class, false);
        String[] titleList = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.title_array);
        String[] grossList = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.gross_array);
        String[] dateList = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.date_array);
        for (int i = 0; i < titleList.length; i++) {
            Lab8_082588FetchDetails item1 = new Lab8_082588FetchDetails();
            item1.setTitle(titleList[i]);
            item1.setDate(dateList[i]);
            item1.setGross(grossList[i]);
            root.put(item1.getTitle(), item1);
            db.setRoot(root);
        }

    }

    String filter = "";
    ArrayList<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> items = root.getPrefixList(filter);
    results = new ArrayList<Lab8_082588FetchDetails>();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Lab8_082588FetchDetails sr = new Lab8_082588FetchDetails();
        sr.setTitle(items.get(i).getTitle());
        sr.setGross(items.get(i).getGross());
        sr.setDate(items.get(i).getDate());
        results.add(sr);
    }

    adapter = new SampleCustomAdapter(results);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
}
```

My "Add Movies" case in the OnActivitiesResult:

```
    case ADD_MOVIE:
            Lab8_082588FetchDetails newMovie = new Lab8_082588FetchDetails();
            IgnoreCaseComparator ignoreCaseAdd = new IgnoreCaseComparator();
            NumberFormat formatterAdd = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");

            newMovie.setTitle(data
                    .getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Add.TITLE_STRING));
            newMovie.setGross("$"
                    + formatterAdd.format(Double.parseDouble(data
                            .getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Add.GROSS_STRING))));
            newMovie.setDate(data
                    .getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Add.DATE_STRING));
            results.add(newMovie);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Collections.sort(results, ignoreCaseAdd);

            Index<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> rootAdd = (Index<Lab8_082588FetchDetails>) db
                    .getRoot();
            rootAdd.put(newMovie.getTitle(), newMovie);
            db.setRoot(rootAdd);

            break;
```

My CustomAdapter initialization of Perst:

```
   Index<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> root = (Index<Lab8_082588FetchDetails>) db
            .getRoot();
    String filter = "";
    ArrayList<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> items = root.getPrefixList(filter);
```

My finish(); and AbsolutePath functions:

```
       public void finish() {
    // close the DB so all changes are saved
    db.close();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Saving DB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    super.finish();
}

private String getAbsolutePath(String databasePath) {
    try {
        // MODE_APPEND is needed or else the file will auto-delete
        openFileOutput(databasePath, Context.MODE_APPEND).close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    databasePath = getFileStreamPath(databasePath).getAbsolutePath();

    System.out.println("Initializing: " + databasePath);
    return databasePath;
}
```

My problem: I've managed to figure out that

```
   rootAdd.put(newMovie.getTitle(), newMovie);
            db.setRoot(rootAdd);
```

Is the part that does the adding, however, due to the lack of Internet resources, and no function lists, I have a problem with figuring out the other functions that correspond to the Delete functions

UPDATE:

I also tried using this line in delete which looks like this:

```
case R.id.contextdelete:
        int pos = info.position;
        String title = results.get(info.position).getTitle();
        results.remove(pos);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Index<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> rootDelete =   (Index<Lab8_082588FetchDetails>) db
                .getRoot();
        rootDelete.remove(title);
        db.setRoot(rootDelete);
```

However it gives something along the lines of "Key Not Unique."

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out now. Me and my friend were working on this one. We tried putting

```
  case R.id.contextdelete:
        int pos = info.position;
        String title = results.get(info.position).getTitle();
        results.remove(pos);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Index<Lab9_082588FetchDetails> rootDelete = (Index<Lab9_082588FetchDetails>) db
                .getRoot();
        rootDelete.remove(title, results.get(info.position));
        db.setRoot(rootDelete);

        return true;
```

with the .remove function having the parameter of an Object and your custom fetch data class (In this case, Lab9_082588FetchDetails). It turns out that the initial .remove function in the code removes the Key only, and not the Object (in this case, the content) itself.

http://docs.huihoo.com/perst/docs/doc11/org/garret/perst/Index.html

Is a useful website that shows the various Perst functions that can be useful for this sort of application.